# I don't understand what happens with my Range. function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code in VBA for an Excel project and there is something I don't understand.

My code works, it does what I want. But there is one line I don't understand what is happening exactly.

Here is a part of my code :

```
Dim LastRow6 As Long

Dim LastColumn As Long

LastColumn = Sheets("All").Range("B2:DB2" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row
'LastColumn = Sheets("All").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Row
'LastColumn = Sheets("All").Range("2:2" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row

LastRow6 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B3:B" & LastRow6).Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("All").Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":DB" & LastRow6), Type:=xlFillDefault 'Autofills the formulas in the column selected to the right untill column DB which is the last header of the table

Range("B3").Select
```

Here, LastRow6 is a way for me to find the last cell in column B that has content in it. I use it because I want to select the cells with content in the column and drag their content to the right.

I want column B to be dragged to the right until column DB. This is why I specify in my autofill function **":DB"**.

The line of code that I don't understand is the following :

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("All").Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":DB" & LastRow6), Type:=xlFillDefault 'Autofills the formulas in the column selected to the right until column DB which is the last header of the table
```

Can someone explain me how "&" works?

I want to understand it because I'm trying to find a way to drag the formula to the right if the last column is another one than DB. If I have new headers in my table, I what the autofill formula to be able to adapt to the new number of columns.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator

Comment: Your problem actually has nothing to do with `&`, and everything to do with how not to use a hard-coded column reference (`:DB`).

Comment: So what can I do to make sure my Autofill function works if the number of columns change?

Comment: `"B2:DB2" & Columns.Count` is not accomplishing what you are hoping it does. `&` operator joins two strings together. `Columns.Count` evaluates to a number like 16384. Therefore the resulting string is "B2:DB216384". You turned `Columns.Count` into a row number.

Comment: `Range(...).End(xlToLeft)` moves from the first cell of the range to the left until it encounters a change in contents, either the next blank, when starting on a filled cell, or the next non-blank, when starting on a blank cell. Either way, this will always return "A2" because it is the only cell that is Left of "B2", which is the first cell in the range "B2:DB216384"

Comment: `LastColumn = Sheets(...).Range(...).End(...).Row` I am deeply perplexed at why the variable `LastColumn` is being filled with a value retrieved from the `Row` property of a range. This line is almost certainly not doing what you hope it is.

Comment: @Toddleson - maybe that's why OP never uses `LastColumn`.

Comment: I was thinking about using LastColumn in the autofill line but I don't know how, so I keep it there until I find a way to use it

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to hard-code the last column (`DB`), then determine it:

```
With Sheets("All")
   Dim LastColumn As Long
   LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   
   Dim LastRow As Long
   LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   
   .Range("B3:B" & LastRow).AutoFill _ 
       Destination:=.Range("B3", .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)), _ 
       Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However there is something I don't understand in your lines of code. For the Autofill part, how can you begin a line with .Range(......etc.)?

Moreover, when I add your code to my program, it says that "Duplicate declaration in current scope". I don't know why it says that because I checked and there is no duplicate declaration :/

Comment: The `.Range` refers to `With Sheets("All")`.

Comment: "Duplicate declaration in current scope".... likely you already have an instance of `Dim LastColumn As Long` and/or `Dim LastRow As Long`.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Formulas

- To copy formulas, you can use the [`Range.Formula`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula) property which is more efficient than the [`Range.AutoFill method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill).
- If you need to use the latter, replace `.Formula = .Columns(1).Formula` with

  ```
  .Columns(1).AutoFill Destination:=.Cells, Type:=xlFillDefault
  ```

  in the following code.
- It is assumed that there is nothing (related to the [`Worksheet.UsedRange property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange)) in the entire columns to the right and in the entire rows below the range of interest.

```vb
Sub CopyFormulas()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All").UsedRange
        With .Worksheet.Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
            .Formula = .Columns(1).Formula
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> The line of code that I don't understand is the following :
>
> ```
> Selection.AutoFill  Destination:=Sheets("All").Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":DB" & LastRow6), Type:=xlFillDefault 'Autofills the formulas in the column selected to the right until column DB which is the last header of the table
> ```
>
> Can someone explain me how "&" works?

The `&` token in VBA has two meanings, depending on context, i.e. how it's used (or sometimes, accidentally *misused*).

##### Type Hint: Long

If it's immediately after an identifier, then it's a *type hint* if that's not what you intended then you might be looking at an accidentally missing space between the identifier (or literal expression) and the `&` operator:

> ```
> MsgBox "Hello, "& Name& "!"
> ```
>
> <sub>The `&` here is a *type hint* for a `Long` Integer, hence the syntax error.</sub>

Actual legal uses would include these:

> ```
> Dim Value& '<~ As Long
> Value& = 42& '<~ Long literal
> Debug.Print "Value is a " & TypeName(Value&)
> ```
>
> <sub>One of these things is not like the others...</sub>

They are there for historical/compatibility reasons, it's just how types were declared way back when, in the times before the advent of the `As` clause. Nowadays we typically prefer readability over terseness.

But that's not why we're here.

##### String Concatenation Operator

When it's used in an *expression*, the `&` symbol is an *operator* that yields a `String` value, so its left-hand and right-hand sides (LHS and RHS, respectively) operands get *coerced* into strings as the expression is evaluated:

```
Dim Name As String
Name = "World"
MsgBox "Hello, " & Name & "!"
```

In the above snippet, the `Name` variable is declared as a `String` and its value is set to the string literal `"World"`. When the `MsgBox` function call is being prepared, the arguments get evaluated; the `MsgBox` function accepts a `String` first parameter named `prompt`, so that's what is being evaluated: a string value (`"Hello, "`) that we concatenate with the RHS operand, a variable that evaluates to `"World"`. Now at this point we have the string value `"Hello, World"`, but then that's the LHS operand of another concatenation, this time with the string value `"!"`. The resulting string is the argument that `MsgBox` receives into its `prompt` parameter.

---

The expression `ActiveCell.Address & ":DB" & LastRow6` might evaluate to `"A1:DB10341"`, and that's the string argument that gets passed to a (implicitly late-bound) `Worksheet.Range` call off a worksheet named "All", (implicitly) from the `ActiveWorkbook`. The resulting object reference is passed as the `Destination` parameter of the `Range.AutoFill` method, as the *named argument syntax* says (`Destination:=...`).

> ```
> Selection.AutoFill  Destination:=Sheets("All").Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":DB" & LastRow6), Type:=xlFillDefault
> ```

`Selection` is whatever is currently selected in Excel. It could be a chart, it could be a shape or a button, ...or it could be a `Range`. The type is `Object`, which means `AutoFill` (or any other member call) is late-bound and there's no IntelliSense when you type out or edit the argument list, either. Declare and use a `Range` variable instead - it's an object reference, so we use the `Set` keyword to assign:

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All")

Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Sheet.Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":DB" & LastRow6) 

Dim Target As Range
Set Target = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B" & LastRow6) 'sure that's the right sheet?

Target.AutoFill Destination, Type:=xlTypeDefault 'you get parameter IntelliSense here
```

So that's it: the line is a member call to `Range.AutoFill` with its arguments. By pulling complex argument expressions into a local variable like this, readability is improved, and everything is early-bound and compile-time checked, so no typo can come throw a run-time error 438 anymore (even more so with `Option Explicit` at the top of every module)!